# curl: (7) Failed to connect to after ms: Bad file descriptor

Tags: macos, curl, file-descriptor, iterm2

My native curl command isn't working anymore when I execute it from my iTerm2 terminal on Mac OS X. I'm using zsh, but even in plain bash, it doesn't work.
Strangely when I try the native Terminal app, the same curl version works for both zsh and bash without any problems. Below is the output I get when I try to access google.com

```
*   Trying 108.177.15.138:80...
* connect to 108.177.15.138 port 80 failed: Bad file descriptor
*   Trying 108.177.15.100:80...
* connect to 108.177.15.100 port 80 failed: Bad file descriptor
*   Trying 108.177.15.113:80...
* connect to 108.177.15.113 port 80 failed: Bad file descriptor
*   Trying 108.177.15.139:80...
* connect to 108.177.15.139 port 80 failed: Bad file descriptor
*   Trying 108.177.15.102:80...
* connect to 108.177.15.102 port 80 failed: Bad file descriptor
*   Trying 108.177.15.101:80...
* connect to 108.177.15.101 port 80 failed: Bad file descriptor
* Failed to connect to google.com port 80 after 48 ms: Bad file descriptor
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to google.com port 80 after 48 ms: Bad file descriptor
```

When I install another version of Curl with Homebrew, I don't have any issues executing that in iTerm2. Does anybody have a clue what the problem might be? Perhaps a permission issue for iTerm2.

#### Curl

```
curl 7.79.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0) libcurl/7.79.1 (SecureTransport) LibreSSL/3.3.5 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.45.1
Release-Date: 2021-09-22
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz MultiSSL NTLM NTLM_WB SPNEGO SSL UnixSockets
```

#### Curl (HomeBrew)

```
curl 7.82.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.3.0) libcurl/7.82.0 (SecureTransport) OpenSSL/1.1.1n zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.2 libidn2/2.3.2 libssh2/1.10.0 nghttp2/1.47.0 librtmp/2.3 OpenLDAP/2.6.1
Release-Date: 2022-03-05
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz MultiSSL NTLM NTLM_WB SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd
```

#### Mac OS X

12.3

#### iTerm2

3.4.15

Answer (score -2):

For some reasons iTerm have an issue when it's located in the `/Applications` folder.
If you move it to the `/Users/<Your Username>/Applications` it works just fine as well as in any other folder than `/Applications`.

Another interesting fact is that it's even enough to rename the application to make it work. For instance `iTerm.app` does not work but `iTerm 2.app` works just fine.

It might be both related to the iTerm or to the system itself. Beta version of iTerm have exactly the same issues.

I was not able to identify what is the reason for such behavior nor relevant ticket in the iTerm repository yet.